# Drag kinetic elements beyond the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

You can drag things beyond the canvas area by binding the `mousemove` event to the window rather than the canvas, is there a way to do this with the `kinetic.js` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is do-able, but not with the kineticjs API.

First bind 'mouseout' to the canvas element. Then when you do dragstart on an element save it to a temporary variable. Then once you leave your canvas area, the mouseout is fired and you can read from the saved element. The real trick will be to 'convert' the item in kineticjs to an item which the outside DOM will recognize.

Comment: What you could do is just extend the canvas when the mouse leaves it. The new kineticjs4.3 allows you to continue dragging when you leave the canvas area.

Comment: Thank you for answering this :), I'll have to go back and try this again.